# federation support in wso2 identity server

Tags: wso2

Hi I started using WSO2 identity server and I am wondering that it only support WS-Trust(Passive) protocol. I want to implement WS-Fed (Active) in my Java Application.

How can I achieve this using WSO2 identity server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WSO2 IS only supports the WS-Federation Passive profile.

Comment: if you have any link explaining the same please share

Comment: You can check it out in the standard product documentation features section. [1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Identity+Server+Features Configs at [2] https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Configuring+Federated+Authenticators+for+an+Identity+Provider